# How does the GetAttr function work over here?

Tags: vba, file

I've got some working code from Stackoverflow that says if a file is found or not.
However why does this "IsFile = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)" work?
GetAttr returns a number 16, if it's not a file, but I am not sure about the inequality that takes place here.

```
MsgBox (IsFile(fName))


End Sub
Function IsFile(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsFile = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
End Function
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hds568h4(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: this is checking for a directory not a file :)

Comment: It works for a directory or a file ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is actually how is the `IsFile` function working rather than just how is the `GetAttr` function working so I will explain the `IsFile` function.

When `GetAttr(fName)` is evaluated, it will cause an error if the file doesn't exist.  You don't see this error and code execution continues because of the `On Error Resume Next` statement.  Try commenting out the `On Error Resume Next` statement to verify this for yourself.  If the file does exist then `GetAttr(fName)` evaluates to an enum, which is of type long.  `vbDirectory` is also an enum with a value of 16.

This line:  `(GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory)` is a logical comparison that is forcing a bitwise comparison.  If the file doesn't exist, meaning `GetAttr(fName)` has caused an error, then then code keeps executing due to the `On Error Resume Next` statement.  So the comparison becomes is `vbDirectory` not equal to `vbDirectory` (i.e. - is 16 <> 16), which evaluates to false.  So the whole `IsFile` function returns false (i.e. `IsFile(fName)` = false), meaning the file doesn't exist, which is what we would expect.

If the file does exist, then no error occurs and this whole line is evaluated: 
 `((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)`

The logical comparison is forcing this part to evaluate to a boolean: `(GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory)` and it will always evaluate to false due to the bitwise comparisons being done to the available enums.  False is equal to zero.  So the next comparison becomes this:  is zero not equal to 16?**  This will always evaluate to true, which makes our statement `(IsFile(fName))` true, which is what we would expect.

**is zero not equal to 16 
`((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)`
`(0 <> vbDirectory)` 
`(0 <> 16)` 
`(0 <> 16)` = true

Comment: Appreciate the breakdown! I had started to customize a similar function and had Removed the Resume Next to add my own error handling. It would error out and I couldn't figure out what was going wrong as I had assumed that upon checking the directory it would just return false if not found... Glad I Googled it.